# Is there any visualization tool for .flac audio file or .ts audio file?

Tags: audio, data-visualization, audio-streaming

I am pretty new with processing audio file. '
I want to build a web app that can take audio file and turn the into visualization for user like this https://github.com/CrowdCurio/audio-annotator

Right now I want to research on visualize audio datas. Original data that was stored in S3 come in two form .ts and .flac. That's why I want to ask if there's any visualization tool which can directly use .ts or .flac audio file.

Because right now the solution I think of will be first convert them into .wav or .mp3, so most visualization tool can process them, but .wav file is really storage-wasting as far as I know.

So if you know any approach or tool to do this. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio visualization requires audio data.  Your compressed audio isn't audible until decoded.  Therefore, you must decode them to PCM before visualizing.

This doesn't require that you store the files as WAV, but you'll at least have to decode them on-the-fly.